# Can't add simple product to cart

Tags: cart

I'm trying to add a simple product to the cart, but addProduct() is failing.

For what it's worth, I'm running the code from inside the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event.

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

//exit('a'); // when uncommented, this does get outputted
$cart->addProduct($secondaryProductId, $primaryProductQty);
//exit('b'); // when uncommented, this does not get outputted.
```

The `$secondaryProductId` variable is type integer and is value 103, a simple product with that ID exists and the product is enabled.

The `$primaryProductQty` variable is type integer and is value 1

Answer (score 1):

I have realised the problem.

Magento's $cart->addProduct() method actually triggers the checkout_cart_product_add_after event, and whilst this was causing recursion, it wasn't causing infinite recursion, but the second call to my event's code (from the recursion) was causing some other invalid code to run.